# SHA1 Hash algorithm issues

Tags: c#, .net, hash-function, cryptographic-hash-function

I'm attempting to store a user's password in my program, but I don't want to store it in plain text. Therefore, I'm hashing it and storing that instead, and when the user needs to enter his password upon the program start (to protect against unauthorized users), I'm hashing the entered password and comparing the two hashes.

However, the following code is generating the same hash for almost any password entered. Can anyone either tell me how to fix the following code, or direct me to a better hash function?

```
public static string getSHA1(string userPassword)
{
    return BitConverter.ToString(SHA1Managed.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(userPassword))).Replace("-", "");
}
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: You should use a salted SHA512 hash, or, preferably, bcrypt.

Comment: @SLaks: Would you like to provide some code? I'm very new to the encryption game, and need all the help I can get. I'd gladly accept it as an answer if you would! If not, thanks for the head start.

Comment: http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/10/bcrypt-dotnet-strong-password-hashing-for-dotnet-and-mono.ashx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I plugged your function into a new project and it seemed to be working OK, so check how the password is being supplied to the function. I'd be wary of using `Encoding.Default` instead of an explicit coding, as it says it's system-dependent.

Here's the one I made:

```
    public static string getSHA1(string userPassword)
    {
        return Convert.ToBase64String(new SHA1Managed().ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(userPassword)));
    }
```

Note: as pointed out in the comments, doing password storage/matching this way is bad:

- you are using a fast hashing algorithm. You want password hashing to be slow to mitigate brute-force attacks. [Bcrypt](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/10/bcrypt-dotnet-strong-password-hashing-for-dotnet-and-mono.ashx) does a good job of this.
- you are not salting your hash. Salting means adding some random data to the password prior to hashing, then storing the random data along with the hash. This makes rainbow tables (huge hash to password maps) useless.

Comment: Thanks very much for the information. Should I use a single salt for all hashing that I do?

Comment: No, your salt must be different for each user. The aim is to force an attacker to brute-force each user's password separately, instead of being able to doing every user in parallel.

Comment: I see, so for each user, a single salt value can be used for all hashing, but each salt needs to be different for each user. Thanks again!

Comment: If an attacker already knows the hash he probably knows the salt to. Nevetheless salting helps to avoid that two passwords are recognized as the same by comparing their hash values, though using individual salts is advised.

Comment: You must assume that the attacker has gotten your DB and knows both salt+hash. You want the attacker to have to combine their password dictionary with the salt of each individual user, hash it and compare. If you don't consider that strong enough, you're using the wrong hash algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Use somehting like this

```
    private static string GetSHA1(string text)
    {
        UnicodeEncoding UE = new UnicodeEncoding();
        byte[] hashValue;
        byte[] message = UE.GetBytes(text);

        SHA1Managed hashString = new SHA1Managed();
        string hex = "";

        hashValue = hashString.ComputeHash(message);
        foreach (byte x in hashValue)
        {
            hex += String.Format("{0:x2}", x);
        }
        return hex;
    }
```